# Validação array POST php

Tags: php, html5

Abaixo uma table na minha view, preciso que ao marcar a coluna no checkbox não seja enviado os dados para minha outra página, ou fazer uma verificação na hora que busca o POST.

[image: inserir a descrição da imagem aqui]

View:

```
<div class="large-12 columns" id="tabela" style="overflow-y:  scroll; height: 80%; border: 0px solid;">
        <div class="TableCSS">
            <form method="POST" action="../controller/precontEnviaEmail">
                <table>
                    <thead>
                        <tr>
                            <th>Nome</th>
                            <th>Email</th>
                            <th>Nº Fatura em atraso</th>
                            <th>Ação</th>
                        </tr>
                    </thead>
                    <tbody>
                        <tr>
                            <td><input type="text" value="teste1" name="nome[]"></td>
                            <td><input type="text" value="email@email.com.br" name="email[]"></td>
                            <td><input type="text" value="666666666" name="fatura[]"></td>
                            <td><input type="checkbox" value="" name="valida[]"></td>
                        </tr>
                        <tr>
                            <td><input type="text" value="teste2" name="nome[]"></td>
                            <td><input type="text" value="email@email.com.br" name="email[]"></td>
                            <td><input type="text" value="666666666" name="fatura[]"></td>
                            <td><input type="checkbox" value="" name="valida[]"></td>
                        </tr>
                    </tbody>
                </table>
            </div>
            <input type="submit" class="tiny button">
        </form>
    </div>
```

Precontroller:

Aqui validar se o checkbox estiver preenchido não pegar os dados da linha da tabela só pegar o que não está marcado.

```
$nome = $_POST['nome'];
$email = $_POST['email'];
$fatura = $_POST['fatura'];
$valida= $_POST['valida'];

//Validação
```

Comment: Já tentou alguma coisa na validação que precisa fazer?

Comment: Tentei mas nem postei por que não vai agregar o que eu preciso, só preciso que valide. Sei como fazer  se fosse somente 1 dado, porém é array. Seria algo simples tipo se isset checkbox pega os dados da linha da tabela para mim tratar depois se tiver marcado descarta, algo assim.

Comment: @Kevin.F , editei minha resposta, agr funciona

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Uma forma de fazer é gerar um *array* associativo a partir do formulário já relacionando os dados de cada registro. Algo como:

```
<tr>
  <td><input type="text" name="registros[0][nome]" value="teste1"></td>
  <td><input type="text" name="registros[0][email]" value="email@email.com.br"></td>
  <td><input type="text" name="registros[0][fatura]" value="666666666"></td>
  <td><input type="checkbox" name="registros[0][valida]" value="1"></td>
</tr>
```

> **Nota:** o valor do índice, exemplificado como 0, deve ser incrementado manualmente.

Assim, ao invés de gerar quatro *arrays* distintos, será criado apenas um. Por exemplo, o `$_POST` seria algo como:

```
$_POST = [
    'registros' => [
        [
            'nome' => '...',
            'email' => '...',
            'fatura' => '...',
            'valida' => '...'
        ], [
            'nome' => '...',
            'email' => '...',
            'fatura' => '...',
            'valida' => '...'
        ], [
            'nome' => '...',
            'email' => '...',
            'fatura' => '...',
            'valida' => '...'
        ], 
        ...
    ]
];
```

Desta forma você poderá utilizar a função `array_filter` para pegar somente os registros que possuem `valida` igual a 1:

```
$validados = array_filter($_POST['registros'], function ($it) {
    return isset($it['valida']) and $it['valida'] == 1;
});
```

Comment: Legal, assim acho que fica mais organizado. Uma dúvida faço um cont para ir adicionando dinamicamente o número no registros[0] ?

Comment: @Kevin.F Depende como você gera o HTML. Se é via PHP ou JS, sim, pode utilizar uma variável `count`. O importante é que mantenha o mesmo valor entre as colunas do mesmo registro, senão cada linha gerará um registro diferente, fazendo algo como `registros[]['nome']`.

Comment: Essa função array_filter armazena os dados dentro da variavel $validados se o valida for igual a 1 é isso ?

Comment: @Kevin.F Exato.

Comment: Eu to marcando um checkbox por exemplo e dando um print_r($validados); após a função ta retornando em branco a array, tem algo mais a fazer ?

Comment: Vai depender de como está seu *array* original e sua função. Consegue postar no https://repl.it?

Comment: A função que eu comentei é a sua ai de cima na resposta, vi que retornou dois erros `Undefined index: registros` e `array_filter() expects parameter 1 to be array, null given in`

Comment: Vamos [continuar esta discussão no chat](https://chat.stackexchange.com/rooms/78190/discussion-between-anderson-carlos-woss-and-kevin-f).

Answer (score 0):

No `PHP`, se o `checkbox` estiver marcado ele vai aparecer com sua respectiva chave, então basta dar `unset()` no array `$_POST` que tenha a chave com o `checkbox` marcado, assim:

```
if(isset($_POST['valida'])){
    foreach ($_POST['valida'] as $key => $value){
        foreach ($_POST as $keyPost => $valuePost){
            unset($_POST[$keyPost][$key]);
        }
    }
}
```

No primeiro `foreach()` ele pega cada `checkbox` que foi marcado;

No segundo, para cada checkbox marcado, ele verifica o array `$_POST` e da `unset()` em todos os subarrays correspondentes à chave do `checkbox`;

Comment: Lembre-se que `$_POST['valida']` será um *array* com todos os checkbox da tela e não apenas um.

Comment: KKKK cara que vacilada, vou editar

Comment: Com esse seu código ta pegando somente os dados do teste2 indiferente do que eu marco nos checkbox.

Comment: Estranho, fiz um teste com o seu codigo mesmo e funcionou, até adicionei mais 5 testes, e funcionou perfeitamente

Comment: Você pega os outros post dentro do ultimo foreach ?

Comment: sim, o ultimo vai apagar todos os que possuem a mesma chave